# Count number of JSON objects - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

Example JSON:

```
{ "image" : "http:\/\/www.domain.com\/blah\/blah\/blah\/5yph0gbfj3ip41a.jpg",
      "0" : { "thing1" : "Hello",
              "thing2" : "06\/21\/2013"
            },
      "1" : { "thing1" : "Goodbye",
              "thing2" : "06\/28\/2013"
            }
}
```

How can I count the number of times the `"0" : {whatever}` appears? They'd be increasing by one. Like for the above example, I want it to return 2.

I'm reading JSON from an id : `[zoneJSONobject objectForKey:@"thing1"];`

Comment: why exactly should it return 2 in this case? I don't get the logic well

Comment: Sorry, Im explaining it poorly. Because it counts the "0" objects ascending. Like "0" "1" "2" etc.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the `- [NSDictionary count]` method ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/count)) for the total number of keys, and then subtract what you don't want to count if it's present (like `"image"` for example.)

Another approach would be to iterate through the keys like:

```
int keyCount = 0;
for (NSString *key in myDict)
    if (/* the string is a number */ )
        keyCount++;
```

(There are plenty of separate SO articles on testing if a string is a number.)

However, the best approach would be to modify the JSON object to return these dictionaries to you inside an array, that way you don't have to count them before you start iterating.  I'm not sure if that option is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's one leading entry for the image, then all the items you want to count. Then you can use the **subtraction operator:**

```
int n = dictionary.count - 1;
```

Comment: This would work for that one example, but seems pretty fragile.

Answer (score 0):

you want to count the root keys? Use the buit-in NSJSONserialization class to create NSObjects from it.  In this case you will get an NSDictionary. Call its allKeys property and then that's count property!

Comment: Why not just call the NSDictionary's count property?

Comment: Simplier it's true, only wanted to show the solution as "counting the keys"